# how to get the stmt handle through connect handle？

Tags: c++, database, odbc

I use the odbc  connect to database,
In my application scene inside, there may be some stmt class can not be free，
Is there any way I can get through SQLHDBC or SQLHENV to get the stmt handle or stmt info ？

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no method of getting a list of open statement handles from the environment or connection handle.

I would suggest that you wrap your statement handles into some RAII object: Upon construction, the statement handle gets allocated, upon destruction, the statement handle gets freed (and maybe closes all open cursors / results first).

Then just make sure that all statement handle objects are destroyed before you release the connection handle.